# Stream over an object array and collect to map with key as property and object as value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an object, Entity[], which has properties like Fields (Key:value), so to get a field1 value, entity.getField(field1).

I want to create a map <field1Value, Object>

need help in doing it via Arrays.stream().collect using Collector, , the imperative way is below:

```
Entity[] entityRecords; //array of Entity
Map<String, Entity> newMap = new HashMap<>(); 
for (Entity entityRecord : entityRecords) {
 newMap.put( entityRecord.getField(field), entityRecord);
 } 
return newMap;
```

---

Comment: Update the post adding details of what you've tried and where you are stuck

Comment: What did you try? This is almost immediate with the Streams API

Comment: Arrays.stream(entityRecords).collect(Collectors.toMap(Entity::getId, Function.identity()))
Works fine.




but 


Arrays.stream(entityRecords).collect(Collectors.toMap(Entity::getField(field1), Function.identity()))
doesn't.

Comment: You can use a simple lambda expression `Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getField(field1), Function.identity()))` if you actually have a getter with parameter, but such a getter is very uncommon

Comment: @Eritrean  You may as well post an answer with explanations because if you don't someone else will.

Comment: What is `field1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer. I am assuming field is some property in entity

```
private Map<String, Entity> entityToMap() {
    String field = "Somefield";
    Entity[] entityRecords; //array of Entity
    return Arrays.stream(entityRecords)
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getField(field), Function.identity()));
}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked, my eclipse was showing error when i was trying to do getField on e so i wasn't proceeding further, but it resolved it later. Was surprised too that why isn't it working. thanks everyone.